# Cannot add LibTorch-Lite, TensorFlowLiteSwift together as dependency for CocoaPod on M1 MacBook

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, cocoapods, tensorflow-lite, libtorch

I'm trying to add below as dependencies together for my CocoaPod (installing either one works but cannot install both)

s.dependency 'TensorFlowLiteSwift'

s.dependency 'LibTorch-Lite'

'LibTorch-Lite' requires below spec

```
s.static_framework = true

s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/LibTorch-Lite/install/include’,
      'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'
  }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = {
      'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'
  }
```

because I get below error.

```
libtorch.a(empty.cpp.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/var/folders/3x/x73_p70n2tg0gnwq9lct7rmr0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20221219-7300-1w8h64c-PyTorchTensorFlowCocoaPod/Pods/LibTorch-Lite/install/lib/libtorch.a' for architecture arm64
```

However spec 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' causes below error when installing TensorFlowLiteSwift.

```
main.swift:1:8: error: could not find module 'PyTorchTensorFlowCocoaPod' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, at: /Users/steve.ham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dnxlikhybfsytahdpnmquhblzyly/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/PyTorchTensorFlowCocoaPod/PyTorchTensorFlowCocoaPod.framework/Modules/PyTorchTensorFlowCocoaPod.swiftmodule
```

Does anyone know how to install both CocoaPods as dependency? Thanks.

Comment: It seems currently TensorFlowLiteSwift only supports iOS

Comment: Yes that’s right but my question is can you make both LibTorch and TensorFlowLiteSwift in one iOS app because it doesn’t work for me.